# SQL Join two tables with a third table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to create a query that selects the columns `PlayerName , PlayerNumber, Location, PartnerName, PartnerNumber, Location` from the following tables:

- `Players` (Columns: Id, PlayerName, PlayerNumber, LocationId)
- `Partners` (Columns: Id, PartnerName, PartnerNumber, LocationId)
- `Locations` (Columns: Id, Location)

But I cannot figure out how to do that. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How Players and Partners are linked. What is joining key between these two tables.

Comment: To participate in the event, participant(a player and his/her partner) have to register. The register process is recorded in talbe Registration(Id, PlayerId, PartnerId, RegDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the updated query after considering registration table.

```
SELECT players.playername, 
       player.playernumber, 
       L1.location, 
       partners.partnername, 
       partners.partnernumber, 
       L2.location 
FROM   registration R 
       INNER JOIN players 
               ON players.id = R.playerid 
       INNER JOIN partners 
               ON partners.id = R.partnerid 
       INNER JOIN locations L1 
               ON players.locationid = L1.id 
       INNER JOIN locations L2 
               ON partners.locationid = L2.id
```

Comment: It works. location L1 and location L2 - I learn new tips. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simple straight way

```
select PL.PlayerName , PL.PlayerNumber, L.Location, PT.PartnerName, PT.PartnerNumber
from  Players PL, Location L, Patners PT
where L.id = PL.LocationId and L.id = P.LocationId
```

This can also be done using UNION, but am not very sure about that

Comment: This SQL will look for tables called `PL` and `PT` and alias them as `Players` and `Partners`.

Comment: Yeh. Typing mistake. Corrected :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. I am not sure

```
select pl.Id,pl.PlayerName,pl.PlayerNumber,pa.ID,pa.PartnerName,pa.PartnerNumber,l.Location 
from Players as  pl,Partners as pa ,Location as l 
where pl.LocationId = pa.LocationId and l.LocationId = pl.LocationId
and pa.LocationId = l.LocationId
AND l.LocationId = <some id>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select PlayerName , PlayerNumber, Location, PartnerName, PartnerNumber
from Players pl
inner join Partners pa on pl.LocationId=pa.LocationId
inner join Location L on L.id=pa.LocationId
where Location = 'String to search for'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  PlayerName,
  PlayerNumber,
  Location,
  PartnerName,
  PartnerNumber
from players
  left join locations
    on locations.id = players.LocationId
  left join partners
    on partners.LocationId = locations.id
```